# 2 update statements to output clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE b
SET  b.update_flag=0 
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.user_code=b.user_code 
where a.pin_number IS NULL

UPDATE a
SET a.pin_number = Adinfo.dbo.udf_ad_Encrypt(b.pin_number)
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.user_code=b.user_code 
where a.pin_number IS NULL
```

Can someone help me how can I write this with output clause in sql server

Comment: what do you mean, "output clause"? You mean this is for a stored procedure?

Comment: I should use output keyword and get the values from the second update statement and get those values inserted in first update statement. It can be done by using output clause.

Comment: updates have no "output", other than the number of rows they affected, perhaps.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: what value are you expecting to retrieve from your update? Why dont you update first, and then run second update with a help of select statement that will retrieve whatever you want to retrieve based on the first update

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `OUTPUT inserted.*;` ?

Comment: @MarcB SQL Server does have an `OUTPUT` clause for data modification statements.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for `UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)? what isn't clear?

Answer (score -1):

I see what the problem is: `I should use output keyword and get the values from the second update statement and get those values inserted in first update statement. It can be done by using output clause. – Durga`

You just have to change your update statements' places.
 
At first you update `pin_number` in table "b" and then set to "1" all `update_flag` in table "a".

Then you wouldn't need output at all. Only one restriction: you have to wrap it inside of transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

UPDATE a
SET a.pin_number = Adinfo.dbo.udf_ad_Encrypt(b.pin_number)
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.user_code=b.user_code 
where a.pin_number IS NULL

UPDATE b
SET  b.update_flag=0 
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.user_code=b.user_code 
where a.pin_number IS NULL

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Yes. I used this method. but I wanted to get it using output clause.

Comment: I've suggested the easier way. You did not tell WHY you want to use `OUTPUT`. I assume you know how to find the documentation on how to use it.